# How to find what is the requirement of my windows app to run on other windows

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, qr-code

Firstly, I'm new to Visual Studio C#. Recently, I've developed a qr generator & reader using windows form. Is there any way I can find what is the requirement of my windows app to be installed to other computer?

It works fine on my computer (windows 10) and one of my other friend (windows 8) but it doesn't work on my other friend (fresh windows 10) so I figured that there must be something he doesn't install so I tried re-installing .net framework 4.0-4.5 to no avail. Sorry, I've tried googling but couldn't find an answer. Thanks in advance.

EDIT : Sorry, forgot to mention the 'error'. On the windows 10 that doesn't work, there isn't actually any eror, once I double click, the cursor change to loading and after about 3 second it turn back to normal but my program doesn't appear, I checked the task manager but my program isn't listed.

EDIT 2 : I just tried on windows 7, and I got this error "program has stopped working"

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3   Problem Signature
>   01:   QR Code.exe   Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0   Problem
>   Signature 03: 5a080a6c   Problem Signature 04:    QR Code   Problem
>   Signature 05: 1.0.0.0   Problem Signature 06: 5a080a6c   Problem
>   Signature 07: 5   Problem Signature 08:   25   Problem Signature
>   09:   System.IO.FileNotFoundException   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48   Locale ID:  1033   Additional
>   Information 1:    0a9e   Additional Information
>   2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789   Additional Information 3:    0a9e
>   Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: What error message or undesirable behavior do you encounter?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. On the windows 10 that doesn't work, there isn't any erorr, once I double click, the cursor change to loading and after about 3 second it turn back to normal but my program doesn't appear.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Windows Log?  Is it possibly loading off screen?  Does Task Manager show it running?

Comment: Task Manager doesn't show it running, I've updated my post about an error that shows up when I try to run it on Windows 7 Professional. By the way, thanks in advance sir for the reply.

Comment: Take a look at [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), though authored by a third party it is fully endorsed by MS and will show you what file(s) your application is trying to access.

Comment: Thanks in advance sir, Will get back to you once I got the result later as I'm outside right now.. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake sorry for not being able to provide the result asap. Been busy, but, I think the cause might be cause of my visual studio. I tried to recompile/rebuild the program from my friend computer (the one that doesn't work before) and now he can run it, and it even works fine on the windows 7.